# Logistic regression with {-1,+1} labels

Tags: logistic, maximum-likelihood, matlab

I am trying to implement logistic regression where the label space is {-1,+1} instead of the usual {0,1}. I know that I can model this as a 0-1 problem but nevertheless I wanted to see if I can derive this from first principles (using MLE).

The min log likelihood expression I get is: 
$ \  l(\theta) = \Sigma_{i=1}^{m}\ \log(1+exp(-y^{i}\Theta^{T}x^{i})) $
where $\{\dots \ (x^{i},y^{i}) \dots \} $ are the $m$ training examples (x is a $n$-dimensional vector).

So now I try to find the gradient for this and I get: 
$ \frac{\partial l(\theta)}{\partial \theta_j} = \frac{\mu.y.x_j}{1+\mu} $ where $j=1\dots n$ are the indices corresponding to features and $\mu = exp(y\Theta^{T}x)$

However, when I try to solve this with Matlab's [`fminunc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fminunc.html) I do not get any updates on my initial weight vector. My Matlab code for this is:

```
temp1 = exp((-y).*(X*w));
temp2 = temp1.*((1+temp1).^(-1)).*y;
grad  = (X'*temp2);
```

Can somebody point what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: It looks like you lost minus sign (twice) in the gradient.

Comment: Ohhh. Multiplying by gradient vector by -1 fixes my issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Expanding Frank Harrells answer, to derive likelihood function you first need to define the probabilistic model of the problem. In the case of [logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163034/bayesian-logit-model-intuitive-explanation/163039#163039), we are talking about a model for binary target variable (e.g. male *vs* female, survived *vs* died, sold *vs* not sold etc.). For such data, [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) is the distribution of choice. Notice that using $\{0, 1\}$ or $\{-1, +1\}$ coding is *not* a part of the definition of the problem, it is just a way of encoding your data, the labels are arbitrary and can be changed. In this case we decide to use the $\{0, 1\}$ labels because they [have some nice properties](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203993/why-0-for-failure-and-1-for-success-in-a-bernoulli-distribution/204007#204007), but the main problem in logistic regression is [estimating the probability of "success"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/227009/logistic-regression-how-to-call-the-output/228212#228212). We use the $\{0, 1\}$ encoding, because the model is defined in terms of Bernoulli distribution that uses such labels.

If you insisted on defining the likelihood function in terms of a distribution that assigns $1-p$ probability for $-1$ and $p$ probability for $+1$, then you would need to use such distribution in your likelihood function. The distribution would have the following probability mass function

$$
g(x) = p^{(x+1)/2} (1-p)^ {1-(x+1)/2}
$$

what basically reduces to Bernoulli distribution for $(X+1)/2 \in \{0, 1\} $.

Comment: (+1) Rewriting your answer as $$g(x)=p^{(x+1)/2}\,(1-p)^{(x+1)/2}$$would make it more evident that all one has to do here is re-express $x\in\{-1,1\}$ as $(x+1)/2\in\{0,1\}$ and apply the usual result.  Thus, there is nothing to be gained either conceptually or mathematically by the change in coding.

Comment: @whuber thanks, that seems to be more clear.

Answer (score 4):

This is not machine learning.  The tag should be logistic regression and maximum likelihood.  I've corrected this.

It is traditional to have $Y=[0,1]$ in formulating the likelihood function.  But if you want to show that you can get the same result with any coding, choose character values instead of numeric to stay general, e.g., $Y=[A,B]$. Then write out the associated functions, avoiding software code until the very end.

Comment: Ok, but could you please see if what I have done for the {-1,+1} case is correct or not ?

Comment: I'd like to see the general case.

Comment: A lesson to us all -- very once in a while even Frank Harrell will get downvoted. :D

Comment: I don't really understand why it is not machine learning.

Comment: The logistic regression model was invented no later than 1958 by DR Cox, long before the field of machine learning existed, and at any rate your problem is low-dimensional.

Comment: Kindly do not downvote an answer unless you can show that it is wrong or irrelevant.

Comment: In case it's needed, let's stress that while using 0 and 1 may be a convention, but it's the best convention by far, allowing a direct interpretation of means as observed proportions and of the model as predicting probability. (Me too on the downvoting: it's hard to interpret the 2 downvotes here except as personal irritation about the comment on machine learning. I added a +1 to do what I can.) Cf. comments in @Tim's answer.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the answer from @Tim , I think I understand the use of transformation in the Bernoulli distribution, but I also got confused. When using the log-likelihood for the response y={-1,1}, we use

$$
\begin{aligned}
logit \frac{P(x_{t})}{1 - P(x_{t})} &= X_{t}^{T}\beta_{t}\\
P(x_{t}) &= \frac{exp(X_{t}^{T}\beta_{t})}{1 + exp(X_{t}^{T}\beta_{t})} \\
\end{aligned}
$$
that is 
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(y=1|X) &= P(x_{t}) = \frac{exp(X_{t}^{T}\beta_{t})}{1 + exp(X_{t}^{T}\beta_{t})} \\
P(y=-1|X) &= 1 - P(x_{t}) = \frac{1}{1 + exp(X_{t}^{T}\beta_{t})} \\
\end{aligned}
$$
that is
$$
\begin{aligned}
P(y=+1 or -1|X) &= \frac{1}{1 + exp(-y*X_{t}^{T}\beta_{t})}
\end{aligned}
$$
Then the log likelihood is
$$
\begin{aligned}
log~L = \sum_{t=1}^{n} log ~\frac{1}{1 + exp(-y_{t}*X_{t}^{T}\beta_{t})}
\end{aligned}
$$
After that, we obtain the coefficient estimates.

How to connect this log-likelihood function to the answer from @Tim ?

I think the use of the expression of g(x) in their answers is just trying to unify the expression of p(x) and 1-p(x). But as long as we obtain and hold on to the 
$$
P(y=1|X)
$$
we are good.