# Why 0 for failure and 1 for success in a Bernoulli distribution?

Tags: bernoulli-distribution

Why do we choose these numbers and not for e.g $e$ and $\pi$ for success and failure in an experiment?

What is the logic and how badly would it affect my calculations if I choose other values instead of 0 and 1?

Comment: It makes things mathematically convenient, although using 0 for success and 1 for failure could be equally convenient. Note that, per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution , "The Bernoulli distribution is a special case of the two-point distribution, for which the two possible outcomes need not be 0 and 1".  You are perfectly free to define a two-point distribution whose values are $e$ and $\pi$ (respectively for success and failure in an experiment); it could be called the Oleg distribution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As already noted by *Mark L. Stone*, it is used because of tradition and convenience. It could have been $-1$ and $+1$ as with [Rademacher distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher_distribution), or any other values.

However there are also other reasons that make $0$ and $1$ a convenient choice. First, expected value of Bernoulli distributed random variable is

$$ E[X] = 0\times(1-p)+ 1\times p = p $$

...so it is instantly obvious from the distributions definition. Sample mean is being maximum likelihood estimator of $p$ since taking the arithmetic mean of zeros and ones leads to proportion of ones in the whole sample.

Moreover, we can easily extend Bernoulli distribution to [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), i.e. from modelling single success in single draw, change to modelling $k$ successes in $n$ draws -- it is quite helpful that you can just sum $1$'s to get number of successes.

There are also multiple other reasons why such coding is convenient for computations, to learn more see [Why is gender typically coded 0/1 rather than 1/2, for example?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16689/why-is-gender-typically-coded-0-1-rather-than-1-2-for-example)

Answer (score 4):

Mathematical convenience. Here is an example: if you set the success case to be $1$ and the failure case to be $0$, then you have that the binomial variable $X \sim B(n, p)$, which counts the number of successes in $n$ independent Bernoulli trials $X_i \sim B(1, p)$, with $i = 1, 2, ..., n$, can be written as

$$ X = \sum_i X_i $$

Therefore,

$$ E[X] = \sum_i E[X_i] = np$$

In addition,

$$ V[X]  = \sum_i V[X_i] = np(1 - p)$$