# What's the difference between binary and binomial data?

Tags: distributions, binary-data, definition

I read terms `binary data` and `binomial data` in a textbook. What's the difference between them?

Comment: `binomial data` is an ambiguous word. Sometimes it means "numbers coming from binomial distribution" and sometimes it means =binary data (or dichotomous data). Tim has given a good distinction.

Answer (score 11):

Possibly what is meant is that binary data consists only [of 0's and 1's](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/204007/35989) for "failures" and "successes" (notice that what you consider as a "success" is arbitrary) and follows a [Bernoulli distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution). Binomial data is data that emerged after observing $n$ Bernoulli trials, i.e. it is a sum of Bernoulli random variables and it consists of non-negative integers, it follows a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). I say "possibly" because this should be defined in your textbook and it is the *only* reference that tells you what the author meant.

Comment: @WhiteGirl what are a and b? If you can consider one of them as "success" (1) and second as "failure" (0) then yes. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/204007/35989