# Logistic Regression: How to call the output

Tags: regression, logistic

I'm currently working on a scientific paper and I'm struggle to answer the following question: What is the right term for the output (ranging from 0 to 1) of a logistic regression?

Neither of these works (since being already taken): Certainty, probability, confidence.

Ideas: rank, probability of occurrence, probability of success..?

Comment: "Fitted probability" or "predicted probability".

Comment: Rank is certainly wrong. That refers to first, second, third, etc., which does not correspond to the predicted probability you get from a logistic regression model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It simply is *probability*, you can call it "predicted" as suggested by others.

I see from the discussion that you disagree with such name, so let me proove you that this *is* probability.

First, recall that if $X$ is a [Bernoulli distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_distribution) random variable parametrized by $p$, then [$E(X) = p$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203993/why-0-for-failure-and-1-for-success-in-a-bernoulli-distribution/204007#204007). Second, take an intercept-only logistic regression model, such model will calculate *mean* of your predicted $Y$ variable. This would be the same as if you calculated it simply taking $\hat y_i = (1/N) \sum_{i=1}^N y_i$. This mean would converge to expected value as $N\rightarrow\infty$, i.e. to $E(Y)= p$. In fact, sample mean is a maximum likelihood estimator of $p$ for Bernoulli distributed random variable. In case of more complicated logistic regression model you [predict conditional means](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173660/definition-and-delimitation-of-regression-model/211229#211229), i.e. conditional probabilities.

Check also [Why isn't Logistic Regression called Logistic Classification?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127042/why-isnt-logistic-regression-called-logistic-classification/127044#127044)

If this still does not convince you, below you can see simple R example showing exactly that case:

```r
set.seed(123)
p1 <- 0.75
Y1 <- sample(0:1, 500, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1-p1, p1))

fit1 <- glm(Y1~1, family = "binomial")

p1
## [1] 0.75

fitted(fit1)[1] # only the first one since all predictions are the same
##     1 
## 0.762

mean(Y1)
## [1] 0.762

q <- 0.3
p2 <- c(0.4, 0.7)
X <- sample(0:1, 500, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1-q, q))
Y2 <- numeric(500)
Y2[X==0] <- sample(0:1, sum(X==0), replace = TRUE, prob = c(1-p2[1], p2[1]))
Y2[X==1] <- sample(0:1, sum(X==1), replace = TRUE, prob = c(1-p2[2], p2[2]))

fit2 <- glm(Y2~X, family = "binomial")

# predicted probabilities vs the true ones
table( ifelse(X==0, p2[1], p2[2]), round(fitted(fit2), 3)) 
##      
##      0.359 0.658
##  0.4   348     0
##  0.7     0   152

# empirical conditional probabilities (conditional means)
tapply( Y2, X, mean )
##         0         1 
## 0.3591954 0.6578947
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the (convincing) code! The table convinced me to go for "predicted probability" !

Answer (score 1):

**Hand-Waving:** The logistic regression is some sort of squeezing a linear regression (fitting a line through you samples) into the range [0,1].
Since you have now some numerical value in the [0,1] range you can actually cal it (TADAM!) *probability!*

**More Rigorous:** What you get is $P(y=white|X)$ or in other words the probability of some sample $y$ to be labeled as $white$ (or whatever two classes that you have) depending on $X$-the data, or more specifically the independent measures of the features represented by $y$.

So to sum it up, $logit(y)$ is the probability of $y$ being ${0,1}$.
If it is only about semantics, you can always drop ***likelihood*** inside.

Comment: I think "probability" doesn't work since the result is gained for a logistic function (sigma) which has nothing to do with the "probability" - neither the bayesian nor the probabilistic one. Same applies for the "likelihood" which is occupied by by the bayesian likelihood (resulting into a posterior distribution in combination with priori knowledge).

Comment: it's not about the logit function as itself, but as using the logit as generalized linear model to fit the data, hence it's can definitely (and usually) describes a probability (usually plotted as a CDF)

Comment: You could call it the expected proportion of successes (1s), but many just call that a probability. The fact that the relationship between that expected probablity and a continuous X is assumed to follow an S-shaped curve changes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ are your independent variables then the output of the logistic regression, let's call it $l(x)$, is the predicted ''conditional'' probability , i.e. the predicted value of the probability conditional on that value of $x$.

So if you have a very large number of subjects with the same value for $x$ then it is expected that a fraction $l(x)$ of these will be 'successes' (or 1).